# How to handle the GitHub situation when `git pull upstream branch_name` gives conflicts when it shouldn't?

Tags: git, github, merge-conflict-resolution

It is strange that there is merge conflict for the following steps:

1. I forked a repo `foo` on GitHub
2. I `git clone` this forked repo to my hard drive
3. After 3 days, somebody committed a lot of code to a branch `xyz`
4. So to make the branch exactly the same on my forked repo, I `git clone` again from the forked repo to a new folder `bar`
5. `cd bar`
6. `git checkout xyz`
7. `git remote add upstream <the URL for foo>`
8. `git pull upstream xyz`

And tons of merge conflict appeared.  I never touched anything in the branch `xyz`. It was another developer who committed a lot of things into `xyz`, so the branch `xyz` should be just updated with all his changed, instead of having merge conflicts.  Later on he said that it had merge conflicts because he `git push -f` and that if he never used `-f`, then it shouldn't have merge conflicts.

How is this situation solved?

Comment: Perhaps the branches on the two GitHub repos diverged?

Comment: `I git clone again from...` why are you cloning _again_, when all you needed to probably do is `git pull`?  Are you very new working with Git?

Comment: I added in the question: "I git clone again from the forked repo to a new folder `bar`".  I have used git quite a bit, but that I usually don't use a forked repo, but use the original repo directly

Answer (score 0):

You should break the `pull` apart into a `fetch` and then `merge`:

`git fetch upstream xyz
git merge upstream/xyz`

Then you'll have to solve the conflicts.

Comment: are you sure... I heard that a fetch and then a merge, is the same as a pull...  The original person who used that branch told me there were conflicts because he used `git push -f`

Answer (score 0):

> Later on he said that it had merge conflicts because he `git push -f` and that if he never used `-f`, then it shouldn't have merge conflicts.

This is correct.

Suppose the original `xyz` branch looked simply like

```
A --- B --- C --- D
```

That is, there are four commits, `D` being the most recent. This is what you cloned.

Now, the other person force-pushes, to make the repo look like this:

```
A --- B --- C --- E
```

That is, commit `D` has been removed, and commit `E` has been added. Consider what happens when you then run `git fetch`:

```
A --- B --- C --- D  <-- local xyz branch
             `
              `--- E <-- remote xyz branch
```

After this is done, there is no way to determine that commit `D` originally came from the remote branch. It is indistinguishable from a commit that you created locally, and therefore, your subsequent `git merge` attempts to preserve its contents.

In this case, you want to completely ignore `D`, you just want to get to `E`. `git reset --hard E` will do this. You can refer to `E` in any of the usual ways, and the most appropriate here to me seems to be `git reset --hard @{upstream}`.